# Input field should not clear after submit using angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

**HTML**

```
<form ng-controller="updatecontroller" ng-submit="updateUser()"><label class="control-label">First Name</label>
    <input type="text"  ng-model="user.userFirstName">
    <label class="control-label">Last Name</label>
    <input type="text"  ng-model="user.userLastName" ><button type="submit" ng-click="updateUser()">Update</button>
</form>
```

**JS**

```
app.controller('updatecontroller', function ($scope, $http, $cookieStore) {

$http.get('http://localhost:8080/myapp/user/'.concat($scope.getUserId) + '?access_token=' + $cookieStore.get("access_token")).
        then(function (response) {
            $scope.user = response.data;
        });$scope.user = {"id": "","userFirstName": "","userLastName": ""}

$scope.updateUser = function () {

    var url = "http://localhost:8080/myapp/user/".concat($scope.getUserId) + "?access_token=" + $cookieStore.get("access_token");
    var method = "PUT";
    $http({
        method: method,
        url: url,
        data: angular.toJson($scope.user),
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        }
    })
};});
```

values will appear in text field. i have to update. the values are getting updated in database. but what i want is.. the updated values should not clear after submit the form.

Thanks!

Comment: share `updateUser()` method ?

Comment: Also note that your submit button is outside the form ... which I guess is why you have had to give it the ng-click.

Comment: Now you've moved the button inside the form you need to remove the ng-click otherwise updateUser will be executed twice. Could you create a plunkr showing the failing behaviour (without the $http stuff).

Comment: what code you aare executing after the updateUser() method?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
You can empty the input filed after get the response from HTTP request

$scope.updateUser = function () {
$http({
    method: 'POST',
    url: 'myUri', 
    data: 'your data'
    headers:'header'
}).then(
    function(res) {
      $scope.user = {"id": "","userFirstName": "","userLastName": ""} //clear the input field here

    },
    function(err) {

    }
);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Place your Submit Button inside the Form Element then try it it will clear the input after the submission.

Comment: Please Asking more detailed? im Not understanding what you need?

Answer (score 0):

your `updateUser()` method seems to be the problem. It's probably clearing `user.userFirstName` & `user.userLastName` (or the whole `user`)

please show us what `updateUser()` is doing to be sure